# Error using gof() function from LogisticDx package in r

Tags: r, logistic-regression

Hi I keep getting the following error message when trying to use the gof() function from the LogisticDx package.

Error in factor(G, labels = dx1[, format(max(P), digits = 3), by = G]$V1) : 
invalid 'labels'; length 6 should be 1 or 5

I can not figure out what causes this error. You can find the code causing the error as well as  code that works below.
If you need more information just let me knows

H

### R version and loaded libraries

R version 3.2.3 (2015-12-10)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 15.04

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base

other attached packages:
 [1] ROCR_1.0-7     gplots_2.17.0  LogisticDx_0.2 xtable_1.8-2   pander_0.5.2
 [6] plyr_1.8.3     Amelia_1.7.4   mice_2.25      Rcpp_0.11.6    knitr_1.11

### Code that produces error

```
PD <- c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
        1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
        1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
        1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
        0, 0, 0)
E <- c(4, 4, 3, 1, 0, 5, 1, 5, 5, 5, 1, 5, 4, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 5,
       0, 5, 5, 5, 5, 0, 0, 4, 5, 2, 4, 5, 4, 5, 3, 0, 5, 3, 3,
       5, 2, 4, 0, 0, 5, 1, 0, 3, 2, 5, 1, 2, 4, 0, 2, 5, 5, 4,
       3, 5, 2, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 5, 2, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 2,
       3, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 1, 3, 0, 2, 0, 3, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 0, 0)

test.data <- data.frame(PD,E)
factor(test.data$PD)

g.error <- gof(glm(PD ~ E,family=binomial,data=test.data),plot=FALSE)
```

### Code that works

```
data(uis)
g.works <- gof(glm(RACE ~ NDRGTX,family=binomial,data=uis),plot=FALSE)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem occurs in line 397 in the source code
https://github.com/dardisco/LogisticDx/blob/master/R/gof.R

```
### Hosmer-Lemeshow
    ## sort by probability
    dx1 <- dx1[order(P), ]
    ## base group size
    gs1 <- dx1[, sum(n) %/% g] # Line 393
    g1 <- rep(gs1, g)
    ## remainer
    mod1 <- dx1[, sum(n) %% g]
    g1[seq(1, g-1, by=g/mod1)] <- gs1 + 1 # Line 397
```

Here the length of seq(1, g-1, by=g/mod1) does not necessarily equal the remainer of the division of line 393 making sum(g1) not equal to n (ex n=129, g=10). This causes the error on line 399

```
dx1[, "G" := factor(G,
              labels=dx1[, format(max(P), digits=3), by=G]$V1)]
```

Since the last dx1[129,G] is NA when n=129 and g=10. A solution could be

```
g1[seq(1, mod1, by = 1)] <- gs1+1
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue here relates to the number of groups in the Hosmer–Lemeshow test being performed. It appears that the default argument for `gof` is `g=10`, which doesn't seem to work for 129 observations (it does work if you add one more row).
It should work if you set the number of groups to 9.

```
gof(glm(PD ~ E,family=binomial,data=test.data), plot=FALSE, g=9)
```

Maybe someone else can answer *why* this is the case?

Comment: Thanks for the answer, why this problem occur I do not know but since it solved my problem I will mark the question as answered.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, very useful, playing with the g = number solved my problem!